# Finding the type of dynamic objects in c#

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have a list of dynamic objects. At runtime, I would like to find the type of objects in the list so that I can instantiate a new list of that type.

```
List<dynamic> list1= new List<dynamic>() { new Test() {ID = 1} }
```

I would like to know that the ID is type int so I can use it in a Activator.CreateInstance statement. When I try to get the type using the following statement, I always get "object"

```
Type typeInArgument = list1.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
```

Is there a way to get this type? I saw some similar questions where the suggestion was to use

```
Type unknown = ((ObjectHandle)list1).Unwrap().GetType();
```

But this doesn't compile for the List.

I need suggestions to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like it's working exactly as well as it possibly could.

Because you're using `dynamic`, the greatest common denominator of list elements *is* `object`. Just because you happen only to have one element in there, that doesn't mean the runtime can guarantee that.

As such, you probably have to special-case what you're looking for.

```
Type ret;
if (list1.Count == 0)
    ret = typeof(object);
else
    ret = list1[0].GetType();
```

Of course, that check is redundant if the code you've given us is meant to be taken literally. But I hope you see the point.

You could also add in a check to run through the list and find if all items are the same type, if that's a requirement.

In general, it sounds like this might not be a great time to use `dynamic`. If you need anonymous types, I'd suggest you move over to concrete ones for this. If you're doing what you're doing here, just type it as a `List<Test>`.

Of course, if all you're looking for is essentially a clone of this list, you could do that and have it be right. I've done this as a `foreach` for readability, but LINQ would be a nice option here.

```
List<object> ret = new List<object>();
foreach (var v in list1)
{
    var type = v.GetType();

    ret.Add(/* new instance of type */);
}
return ret;
```

Remember, of course, that this doesn't guarantee you anything more about the types contained, and you'll have pretty well the same issue again when you try and actually read the resultant list.

I would really suggest reevaluating your use of dynamic here. It does allow for some things that wouldn't otherwise be possible, so you might choose to stick with it, but it's worth a second thought.

Answer (score 2):

A `List<dynamic>` doesn't *have* a specific inner type.  The whole point of `dynamic` is that it can be anything.

Instead, you can get the type of an item in the list: `list1[0].GetType()`.
Note that there is no guarantee that the next item is of the same type.